# Класс для вывода из базы sqlite3 + node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite3

Хочу сделать класс для вывода нужной инфы из базы. 
Я новенький в js и думал можно как php просто записать вывод из базы в переменную, потом где-то на странице вывести, но почитал немного и понял что переменная будет выводится еще до того как будет сделан запрос в базу.
Так вот вопрос: можно ли сделать как-нибудь такой класс чтобы выводить инфу из базы где хочешь?
Вот что я примерно хотел сделать:
class

```
class dbclass{
 count(table){
   let sql = `SELECT COUNT(*) as sqlCount FROM `+table;
   db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
   return rows[0].sqlCount;
   });
}
}
module.exports = dbclass;
```

app

```
const dbClass = require("./dbclass.js");
const dbclass = new dbClass();
if(dbclass.count('users')>0)console.log('ok');
```

Если я напишу в самом класс вместо `return` `console.log` он конечно выведет все, но я хотел бы вывести именно тут.
Возможно ли такое?